# Hapijs plugin vs server.bind

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

Is there any advantage in registering a Hapi plugin vs making the underlying node module available through the server context (assuming plugin doesn't add much functionality to the module)? E.g., for mysql I can register a hapi-mysql plugin

```
server.register({
  register: require('hapi-mysql'),
  options: {
    host: "localhost",
    user: "test",
    password: "test"
  }
}, (err) => {
  if(err) {
    throw err;
  }
});
```

and then access it through the server variable

```
var dbPool = server.plugins['hapi-mysql'].pool;
```

The alternative is creating an instance of mysql pool directly

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'localhost',
  user            : 'test',
  password        : 'test'
});
```

And binding it to the server context

```
server.bind({dbPool: pool});
```

I personally prefer the second approach (server.bind), but want to make sure I'm not missing something

Answer (score 2):

The case of passing a database pool instance through `server.bind` is not wrong, a resource that is probably needed in most parts of the application and it will give an easier access. while it is recommended if you have only one plugin you are working on. [check Hammer's comment](https://github.com/hapijs/discuss/issues/182) , `server.app` would be the alternative.

> Server methods are common utilities used around your server, but best
>   to not cross plugin boundaries with them to reduce dependencies.
>
> In general, if you find yourself using a lot of dependencies between
>   your own application plugins, you are doing it wrong.

So plugins are modular components with their own business logic decoupled from any other parts of the system and can be the right solution if your application grows bigger.